# Async Symfony events

Tags: php, symfony, events, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use https://github.com/fervo/FervoDeferredEventBundle in order to have async events to store data in my DB. The event is added to the RabbitMQ Queue correctly but the event listener and the event itself is never executed.

I'm trying in both ways: first letting the listener to do the job and also dispatching manually the deferevent.

Any idea?
Thank you!

#### My code:

in my Controller:

```
$event = new DeferEvent('save.data', new SaveDataEvent($data));
$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('fervo.defer', $event);
```

`SaveDataEvent.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class SaveDataEvent extends Event
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function saveData()
    {
        $data = $this->getData();
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

`SaveDataListener.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Event\SaveDataEvent;

class SaveDataListener
{

    /**
     * @var SaveDataEvent
     */
    public function onSendData(SaveDataEvent $event)
    {

        $data = $event->saveData();
    }
}
```

`services.yml`

```
app.save_data_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\SaveDataListener
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener #fervo_deferred_event.listener
                event: send.data
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `event: fervo.defer` in the YML?

Comment: i understand it as the event that i want to execute, the fervo.defer is the wrapper for my event... but i'm not sure at all

Comment: There is another solution that addresses Symfony async events (that we built). It requires less configuration and more convenient. To make a listener async you just have to add `async: true` attribute to event listener tag and run a enqueue:consume command in the background. More here https://blog.forma-pro.com/symfony-async-eventdispatcher-d01055a255cf

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs, you should fix the `services.yml`:

```
app.save_data_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SaveDataListener
    tags:
        name: fervo_deferred_event.listener
        event: fervo.defer
```

Replace `fervo.defer` with the first value passed to `dispatch()` method if you want, it's the name of the dispatched event.

Comment: But like this i'm going to dispatch the `fervo.defer` event, but the `save.data` event and function will be never executed

Comment: So you'll need to call - >dispatch('save.data', $event). The string in dispatch must match the event name in YML. I suggest to you to look at the Symfony docs about event dispatching

Comment: As far as i understood this bundle, i have to dispatch the `fervo.defer` event and the bundle will dispatch the `save.data` event, that's why i'm using this. Or maybe there is a better approach to do this

Comment: And how the bundle should know to launch the save.data event? That's basic SF event dispatching, the bundle insert itself using the different tag name, the event name is up to you, and it's save.data

Comment: I tried also like this and it's also not working. Like always the event is stored in the RabbitMQ queue but never consumed, but it is published.